# Perl HTML CGI web page error

Tags: html, perl, cgi

This is my perl code for a registration web page. It should append values to a csv page. It compiles perfectly but when I conncet it to my HTML program the web pae actually displays an error. This is the page
http://cs.mcgill.ca/~zviran1/register.html
HELP

```
#!/usr/loca/bin/perl
use CGI;
my $q = CGI->new();
use strict;

my $username = $q->param('username');
my $name = $q->param('name');
my $password = $q->param('password');
my @array = ($name, $username, $password, "\r");
my $line = join(' , ', @array);

print "Content-type: text/html \n\n";
my $file = 'Members.csv';
open (FILE, '+>>$file') or die "Cannot open file";
my $inputLine = <FILE>;
while($inputLine = <FILE>)
{
if(index($line, $username) != 4){
print "<HTML>\n";
print "<HEAD>\n";
print "<TITLE> Error Page </TITLE> \n";
print "</HEAD>\n";
print "<BODY>\n";
print "The username you have entered is already in use.";
print "<br><a href=\"index.html\">Home Page</a> \n";
print "<br><a href=\"register.html\">Registration Page</a> \n";
print "</BODY>\n";
close(FILE);
}
else {
#seeking to the end of the file to append
seek(FILE, 0, 2);
print FILE $line;
}
}
close(FILE);
```

Comment: "actually displays an error" — What error?!

Comment: Click on the link and try to register. "Internal server error"

Comment: And what is the internal server error? It's recorded in your server logs, not sent to the browser so I can't tell from here.

Comment: **Danger**: You aren't hashing your passwords and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: Using a CSV file as a database is a terrible idea. If you aren't going to use a real RDBMS then at least use something like SQLite. (And if you are going to use a CSV file, then use a CSV library that will properly escape input)

Comment: CGI is inefficient at best, and CGI.pm is going to be removed from the next release of Perl. Use [PSGI and Plack](http://plackperl.org/) instead. If you really want to use CGI then Plack has [a CGI handler](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Handler::CGI).

Comment: the error was premature end of header or something like that

Comment: I have to use CGI, and have to use a CSV file :/ it compiles perfectly so it's not a syntax error

Comment: Using Plack doesn't preclude using CGI - I pointed to the CGI handler for it. CSV is still a terrible idea, but you really should use a library for it rather then just printing with commas. Try executing the script (on the command line) with `./foo.cgi` instead of `perl foo.cgi`.

Comment: `my $inputLine = <INPUT>;` Look at this line. Do you `open` a filehandle named `INPUT` anywhere prior to this? What do you expect will happen when you try to read from an unopened filehandle? (You can find out by writing a small test program on the command line, e.g.: `perl -Mstrict -we 'my $foo = <INPUT>'`) The same applies to `PTR` later in your script.

Comment: You're getting an internal server error. And that's Perl's way of telling you to look into the web server error logs for more details.

Comment: "the error was premature end of header or something like that" - One of the most important attributes of a programmer is attention to detail. This description does not bode well :-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your Perl interpreter is where you want it to be? Your shebang line is

```
#!/usr/loca/bin/perl
```

which is probably missing an 'l'. When you run the script locally via `perl myscript.pl` it ignores that line but when you run it under a webserver like Apache, it's actually used to find the Perl interpreter.

Other than that, have a look at your web server log (you should be able to access the error log even on simple hosting providers) because the error page your browser gets is merely the web server saying 'Hey, something went wrong there'.